# proper way to set PreparedStatement parameter to null under postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

im using JDBC4 (over JDK6) to connect to postgresql 9.0 using their latest JDBC4 driver.

```
conn = dpaDs.getConnection();
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("delete from fss where f_id=? and f_lastmodified=?");
UUID target = UUID.fromString("8c5c5ac2-3a2a-49f3-ae48-29226d6ea3e7");
stmt.setObject(1, target, 1111);
//non of these work
//stmt.setNull(2,93);
//stmt.setObject(2,null, 93);
//stmt.setObject(2,null, java.sql.Types.NULL);
//stmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.NULL);
int rowCount = stmt.executeUpdate();
int g = 8;
```

what is the correct way to set the 2nd parameter to null ?
i know that i can use "where ... f_lastmodified is null", but is there no way to get around this?

Comment: postgresql jdbc is the only database that does not yet support your valid approach. See ["Add support for setObject(<arg>, null)"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-1938) for a discussion of the industry standard. Try Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, HSQL, Sybase. See [bug](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/3) and the discussion "Cannot pass null in Parameter in Query for ISNULL" at mailing list pgsql-jdbc@postgresql.org for another very compelling use case where the null check is even guarded by an ISNULL condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That won't work.

NULL comparison cannot be done using the `=` operator. If you want to test for NULL, you have to use `and f_lastmodified IS NULL`.

You can't use a parameter in a prepared statement for an IS NULL condition.

Comment: I think that `? IS NULL` is fine in a prepared statement and looks like it solves the OP's problem. There is also the `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` operator although I was unpleasantly surprised to see that PG doesn't seem able to use it with an index.

Comment: `? IS NULL` won't work, because that would require passing a column name as the parameter and that is not supported with PreparedStatements.

Answer (score 0):

If you use named parameters (e.g. :p instead of ?) instead of positional ones then you can do the following,

```
((:p is null and f_lastmodified is null) or f_lastmodified = :p)
```

Which is a bit awkward, but it gets the job done. I have not tried this with jdbc, only Npgsql on .net, but I think it should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

In postgres you can use `is not distinct from` which is effectively a null safe equality check.

If you alter the query to use is not distinct from it will now allow you to set null as parameter 2.

```
delete
  from fss
 where f_id = ?
   and f_lastmodified is not distinct from ?
```